# Angular 7 application development on .Net using visual studio 2015

Tags: angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

Most of the angular 7 application developments are done with Visual Studio Code (open source code editor) as per my google research. I see that angular app can be developed with VS Code still integrated with visual studio 2015 for maintenance like TFS source control and visual studio publish feature for deployments.

Can we use VS Code for writing angular 7 code and manage it in VS studio 2015, as the Asp.Net WebAPI is developed as VS 2015 project for using the existing entity framework class library for data?

Can someone please explain the angular 7 application development setup for .Net application with asp.net WebAPI and keeping it all together for easy maintenance and less confusion for new angular developers?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Client side app like angular doesn't not need to be tie together with server side codes. If I was a new angular developer I would prefer having angular on its own easier to navigate through angular code instead all of the massive overhead with web api, domain layer, etc in 1 big solution.

Comment: ok, but which tool is easy to use for maintain angular code for TFS. Also bootstrap 4 intellisense is not working well even after installing bootstrap plugin in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

1- You should write your WebAPI indipendent from angular, in this shape you will some advantages that you can develop it without depending front-end and some disadvantage that you should implement your API with cors etc.

2- You can use VSCode for angular development or VisualStudio main differance in my opinion is deployment cases. It changes according your target hosting environment.
Also i think visual studio usage more easy and powerfull then vscode. For example you can search any object in visual studio like "Find in files" but you can not do it in vscode without installing a new plugging. But even plugging may become not usefull. Together of all this disadventages vscode provides very clean environment.

3- You know TFS is a revision control system you can store any code on there it is usefull and easy. If you compare with other revison control systems it has some adventages and disadvantages

Comment: Are you recommending to use Visual Studio 2015 for angular development instead VSCode? sorry i didn't understand that from above.

Comment: No i recommend you develop the api with visual studio 2015 or 2017 and develop angular with vscode but use some extra pluggins for vscode

Comment: But bootstrap 4 intellisense is not working well even after installing bootstrap plugin in VSCode.

Comment: i havent used bootstrap in vscode but i used bulma instade. There is no intelisense specified to a library there is many plugging like eslint prittier etc.. for to having better code and finding refferences

Comment: @dewelloper you can look it at